# How to make 'When I press the Android Widget the Button To run at the same time'?

Tags: android

I Question the stackFlow member. "How to make 'When I press the Android Widget the Button To run at the same time'?"

I like to run at the same time. but When I make the Android code, I was failed. Because I use same switch Grammer. I don't know the code.

**I want [ 1. press the button 2. Activity -> 'the other Activity' and 'To runn the Download Manager'**

**' algorithm -> Android Java code '** please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438083/how-to-make-if-i-press-the-button-download-manager-turn-on)?

Comment: @TedHopp Yes This quretion is different my previous question

Comment: In what way is it different? Seems pretty much the same. What have you tried?

Comment: @TedHopp umm... My previous question used a Download manager. it question is only download manager but today question is 'How to make running at the same time' the code..... I'm sorry to bother yoou.

Comment: If you start a download with `DownloadManager` and also start a new activity, the download will happen in the background at the same time the new activity is started. Show us the code that failed and explain how it failed. Then perhaps we can help.

Comment: @TedHopp oh Thanks.. wait a moment, I upload after dinner

Comment: @TedHopp ...  TedHopp! How are you learned the android? Can you give me tips ?.. Tell me a little bit ! If I bother to you you need not tell me the tips.. Thanks :)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/ Practice basic apps till you get confident

Comment: @AmolTate Yes. I not get the answer...

Comment: You could make the service and run it concurrently.